# Stateful EJB преждевременно удаляется контейнером

Tags: java, java-ee, ejb

Реализовываю корзину книг (для интернет-магазина) с помощью Stateful EJB.

```
@Named
@Stateful
public class ShoppingCartEJB {
    private List<Book> shoppingCart = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Book> getShoppingCart() { return shoppingCart; }

    public void addBook() {
        FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Book b = ctx.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(ctx, "#{bookController.book}", Book.class);
        addBook(b);
    }
    public void deleteBook() {  }

    private void addBook(Book book) {
        if(!shoppingCart.contains(book))
            shoppingCart.add(book);
    }

    private void deleteBook(Book book) {
        if(shoppingCart.contains(book))
            shoppingCart.remove(book);
    }

    public int getNumberOfBooks() {
        if(shoppingCart == null || shoppingCart.isEmpty())
            return 0;
        return shoppingCart.size();
    }

    public int getTotalPrice() {
        if(shoppingCart == null || shoppingCart.isEmpty())
            return 0;
        int total = 0;
        for(Book book : shoppingCart)
            total += book.getPrice();
        return total;
    }

    public void clearCart() {
        shoppingCart.clear();
    }

    @Remove
    public void checkout() {
        System.out.println("Remove");
        shoppingCart.clear();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("PreDestroy");
    }
}
```

Добавляться книга при нажатии на кнопку "В корзину", в JSF-странице это выглядит так:

`<h:commandButton value="В корзину" action="#{shoppingCartEJB.addBook()}" />`

А книги в корзине можно посмотреть на другой странице, в JSF-странице это выглядит так:

```
<h:panelGrid id="shopping-cart" columns="2">
    <h:outputLabel value="В корзине содержиться #{shoppingCartEJB.numberOfBooks} книг: " />
    <ui:repeat value="#{shoppingCartEJB.shoppingCart}" var="book">
        <h:link value="#{book.title}" outcome="viewBook.xhtml?id=#{book.id}" />
    </ui:repeat>
    <h:outputLabel value="Общая сумма: " />
    <h:outputText value="#{shoppingCartEJB.totalPrice}" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

Проблема следующая: на странице постоянно показываеться, что книг в корзине нету, хотя при нажатии на кнопку "В корзину" книга в список `shoppingCart` добавляеться (то есть метод `addBook()` работает как положено). Но почему-то при переходе на другую страницу (или возможно из-за других причин) 12 раз вызываеться метод `destroy`, который помечен аннотацией `@PreDestroy`, соответственно stateful ejb удаляется и вместе с ним и список `shoppingCart`. Но почему так происходит?

Comment: Возможно потому, что установлен 20-секундый таймаут, и бин удаляется, если к нему не обратились в течении этого времени?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, если честно, я думал это время пассивизации. И почему он тогда удаляется аж 12 раз во время одной сессии?

Comment: Неа, не оно. Кроме того, частая пассивизация - тоже не хорошо, так как I/O обычно обходится дороже оперативной памяти.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, убрал аннотацию `@StatefulTimeout` и ничего не изменилось :(